# Firestore Update Query not Executing

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having problem with executing Firebase update query . it was working properly before but i dont understand why its having problem today to execute . Following is my code

```
mDb.collection("Users_Collection")
                .document(mAuth.getUid()).update("tokenid"," ").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d("logint","task is sucessfull");
                mAuth.signOut();
                Log.d("logint", "Loged out");
            }
        });
```

Problem is that update command never executes neither it shows any error in console.

**UPDATE: I am also unable to login also . its showing "Error Occured A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
"
Error

Comment: you said that code was working fine earlier so it might have logged you out and your session have been terminated. Have you signed in again before executing this code?

Comment: session is properly working because i am able to log mAuth.getUid() in my code . and if my session had expire than it must show me a null exception in update query

Comment: now i am unable to login also , its showing me "Error Occured A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."

Comment: can u check if even user exists in the firebase authentication console or not?

Comment: yes user exists their i checked . if user is not their than it should have given me a different error , not a network timeout error, right ?

Comment: generate a new JSON configuration from firebase and replace it with existing JSON config file in your project...that should help

Comment: i did, now its showing an error in debug console as "Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating Google Play Services solved the error